# Elastic cloud on Kubernetes (ECK) using helm 3

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, elastic-cloud

Is there a way to run Elastic cloud on Kubernetes (ECK) with helm3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as i know, there is no helm chart for ECK operator however for the `Elasticsearch` stack there is a helm chart available.

Elastic stack helm chart : https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/master/elasticsearch

ECK is operate you can extend Kubernetes orchestration by YAML files or else you can create own helm chart as per need if required.

ECK quick deploy : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-quickstart.html

ECK is providing official support in GKE however i think you have idea about the advantages & disadvantages of using ECK.

Comment: what are the disadvantage with ECK?

Comment: there is free teir but if planning to use in production enterprise edition is not free.

Comment: learning curve for ECK much steeper and for small use case it's better not to use. when you can’t create a production-worthy setup because of pricing. For test and dev, a single node will work fine. When you move to production, you should have no less than a 3-node/2-replica

Comment: With ECK free tire we cannot setup a production ready cluster ? Can you tell what the free tier is lacking?

Comment: if you don't require `field- and document-level access control` you can use free tire, that depends on use case and requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am thinking of deploying ECK as a kubernetes job via helm 3. Do you see any problem with this approach? I am quite new to this k8s and helm so any pointers would really help

Comment: There is no problem but if we look at the official document they are also using YAML file : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-quickstart.html , however, you can definitely create your own helm chart as per need. if the helm is not required direct apply YAML config.

Comment: @HarshManvar I've tried deploy using helm with custom values pass, but throws an error : `unknown field Capabilities, Chart, Files, Release, etc`, which weren't  part of the chart. I don't  know from where its getting these  properties.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, starting ECK 1.3.0, there is an [official Helm chart](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/1.3/k8s-install-helm.html) for deploying the operator.

Comment: Thats for the `eck-operator`. what about deploying customized `eck` using helm ?? like both elasticsearch and kibana should be deployed with custom values.

Comment: It will happen soon: https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/issues/5505.